# Is there a software like Microsoft Bot Composer for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, elasticsearch, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to make a ChatBot that uses Dialog Flow and should be able to pickup Keywords and match it to the Intents. 
I've worked with Microsoft Bot Framework using Luis and deployed a similar bot on Azure but now I have to do the exact same thing but have to deploy that on AWS and use Elastic Search. 
How do I do that? Is there a similar Software available for AWS ?

Comment: Hint: Google this "AWS bot service"

Answer (score 2):

you can use AWS lex for create chatbot,here is the link for aws lex

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/getting-started.html.
```

for performing back-end task like validation and dynamic response from bot side,then you need to use lambda again lambda also AWS tool that provide to how to make server-less bot.

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/using-lambda.html
```

hope this kt will help you.